# Which icon sizes are required for progressive web apps (PWA) as of Q1 2018?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Which application icons and sizes are required for a progressive web app (PWA)? For example, should I include Apple icons if Safari doesn't support PWAs?

It seems like a common need among developers, but at this time, I am not certain if there is an official spec or guidance for it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to include a complete set of icons for **Android**:

```
icon-72x72
icon-96x96
icon-128x128
icon-144x144
icon-152x152
icon-192x192
icon-384x384
icon-512x512
```

There is some helpful tools like https://www.simicart.com/manifest-generator.html/, to create icons.

For **iOS**, you will need:

```
icon-120x120
icon-180x180
```

With square background (can't be transparent background).
A good repository for references at https://github.com/gokulkrishh/awesome-meta-and-manifest

Comment: It is usually a good practice to have multiple dimensions, so I recommend you to use several dimensions.

Comment: `app-manifest.firebaseapp.com` no longer works. I get _Go 1.9 is no longer available._

Comment: The app-manifest firebase app is broken now. Should update this answer.

Comment: for anyone looking for an icon generator 
https://tools.crawlink.com/tools/pwa-icon-generator/
it's missing the iOS sizes tho

Comment: This answer does not explain the question which sizes are actually used or even required.

Answer (score 21):

As per [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/install-prompt#recommendations)

> icons must include a **192px** and a **512px** sized icons

[Here](https://www.spheregen.com/implementing-pwa-behavior-to-asp-net-mvc-5-apps/) is our blog on the same.

Answer (score 13):

For you OCD'ers out there, here's the full list

48x48

57x57 (iOS)

60x60 (iOS)

72x72 (iOS)

76x76 (iOS)

96x96

114x114 (iOS)

120x120 (iOS)

144x144

152x152 (iOS)

180x180 (iOS)

192x192

256x256

384x384

512x512

Answer (score 9):

According to the World Wide Web Consortium's (W3C) App Manifest specification for Progressive Web Apps ([8.7 icons member](http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#icons-member)):

- You may declare multiple icons of various formats and size
- The W3C spec does not identify required or recommended sizes, but allows you to specify attributes (size, format, path) for the icons you provide to allow the user agent to choose the most appropriate within these rules:

  - The user agent must use the LAST icon declared that is appropriate for its use.
  - It must fallback on the next most appropriate if the first one tried fails for any reason.

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#icons) does not list required sizes or formats either, but adds:

- The **sizes** value is a "space separated list of dimensions" for an icon

  - Example: "72x72 96x96"
- The **type** value is optional, but aids the user agent in selecting the most appropriate icon for its use.

Using the rules above, the application can provide conditions on the use of certain icons, such as forcing the PNG for a specific resolution and falling back to SVG for any unspecified sizes and allow the user agent to select the best choice. The benefit of this system is forward compatibility with user agents that have not yet been announced.

**Manifest Icons Example:** (based on W3C spec cited above)

```
{
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/brand_small.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon/brand.ico",
      "sizes": "96x96 128x128 256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon/brand_large.svg",
      "sizes": "257x257"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Actually this incorrect in practice. Chrome/Lighthouse will complain about a missing icon. You should add more sizes to the SVG file (at least `512x512` in above case).

Comment: While, true, do they have the additional sizes documented? I just quoted the spec.

Comment: Not on W3C page, no. But docs by Google suggest otherwise... Also note that it might be a bug in Lighthouse (or Chrome). Which I reported here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/4883

Comment: just curious, in your example, would `brand.ico` be a specific size? It seems that what the `"sizes"` attribute is actually specifying is the aspect ratio? So, if that's the case, why isn't the property/attribute called "aspect-ratio"?

Comment: No, `*.ico` files can have multiple images embedded in them. In the above case `icon/brand.ico` includes three different images with three different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

*This is an old question, but I'll answer it just in case the info might help others.*

**SHORT ANSWER:** You need at least 1 image/png that is 144 x 144 pixels.

The [specification](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#dfn-icons) isn't very helpful as it says everything is optional and leaves it to the device to decide what is required. And this might be why one sees manifests with a long list of icons to cover every possible device.

However, in general a [manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) must include at least 1 image/png that has a minimum size of 144 x 144 pixels.  Smaller images will not work, though it's acceptable to use a larger image such as 192px or 512px. And the device might check that the actual image size matches the size claimed in the manifest.

Aside from the image, most devices require other manifest fields too:  name, short_name, and start_url. Without all of these, the device will not recognized the app as an installable PWA.

There is also a new "id" field which is good to know about: [Uniquely identifying PWAs with the web app manifest id property](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/pwa-manifest-id/)